# Div Overflow to the left

Tags: html, css

I am positioning stuff in my website centered by using calc(50% + whatever I want)

Sometimes I might want to make it 50% - 100px or something like that, but there is a problem. On small browser screens the div will be off the screen to the left.

If it overflows on the right then I am fine because a scroll bar will be there, but if the div is overflowing to the left then you can't view it.

```css
html {
  background: url("http://wallpapercave.com/wp/adsKXLw.png") no-repeat center center fixed; 
  background-size: cover;
}

body {
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 100%;
}

.navbar div, .navbar div p {
  position: fixed;
}

#huge {
  width: 1100px;
  height: 10000px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgb(255, 153, 51);
  background-color: rgba(255, 103, 48, 0.5);
  left: calc(50% - 550px);
  top: 0px;
}


#navbar-background {
  width: 920px;
  height: 110px;
  border-radius: 70px;
  top: 11px;
  left: calc(50% - 460px);
  background-color: rgb(255, 204, 128);
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255, .2);
}

#home-div {
  background-color: rgb(249, 162, 100);
  width: 210px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  left: calc(50% - 430px);
  top: 30px;
  z-index: 2;
  border-top: 1px white solid;
  border-left: 1px solid white
}

#home-div-button {
  background-color: rgb(200, 131, 78);
  width: 215px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 40px;
  left: calc(50% - 425px);
}

#home-text {
  font-family: Comfortaa;
  text-align: center;
  top: 10px;
  left: calc(50% - 415px);
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}



#clan-div {
  width: 90px;
  height: 45px;
  border: 2px white solid;
  left: calc(50%);
  top: 40px;
  border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
}

#clan-text {
  left: calc(50% + 0px);
  top: 26px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Comfortaa;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 10.5px 0px 8px 7.5px;
}

#clan-div-2 {
  width: 90px;
  height: 45px;
  border: 2px white solid;
  left: calc(50% + 100px);
  top: 40px;
  border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
}

#clan-text-2 {
  left: calc(50% + 100px);
  top: 26px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Comfortaa;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 10px 11px 8px 14px;
}

#games-div {
  width: 90px;
  height: 45px;
  border: 2px white solid;
  left: calc(50% + 230px);
  top: 40px;
  border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
}

#games-text {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Comfortaa;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  top: 21px;
  left: calc(50% + 230px);
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
}

#more {
  width: 90px;
  height: 45px;
  border: 2px white solid;
  left: calc(50% + 330px);
  top: 40px;
  border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
}

#more-text {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Comfortaa;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  top: 27px;
  text-align: center;
  left: calc(50% + 330px);
  padding: 12px 7.5px 12px 7.5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>The Own Clan Website</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" text="text/css">
    <link href="script-1.js" text="text/javascript">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="everything">
      <div id="huge"></div>
      <div class="navbar">

        <div id="navbar-background"></div>

        <div id="home-div">
          <p class="navbar-text" id="home-text">THe TITLE</p>
        </div>

        <div id="home-div-button"></div>

        <div class="navbar-div" id="clan-div">
          <p class="navbar-text" id="clan-text">Stuff</p>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-div" id="clan-div-2">
          <p class="navbar-text" id="clan-text-2">More stuff</p>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-div" id="games-div">
          <p class="navbar-text" id="games-text">Thing</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="navbar-div" id="more">
          <p class="navbar-text" id="more-text">Extra Stuff</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Keep on zooming in and you will see what I mean.

Is there anyway to make stuff visible if they overflow to left?

Answer (score 0):

When you center something horizontally only (like in your question), it's better to just use `margin: 0 auto;` on it - nothing else. If that's in another container, you should use `position: relative` on both elements.

```css
div {
  width: 1700px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #111111;
  color: #f0f;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
 <head>
    <title></title> 
</head>
 <body>
    <div>xxx</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I used my actual project for the snippet. Part of it is overflowing to left and you can't see

Comment: so, have you tried to apply `margin: 0 auto` to your project?

Comment: I meant to say look at the snippet again I edited it.

Comment: well: you set all the divs and p-tags in your navbar to position:fixed. Of course that con't work - position: fixed is always relative to the viewport/window, so no matter what you do with the parent (navbar) these will be offset. You really should change this, but please don't expect me to write your code...